# How to view extension privileges in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-extensions

In Google Chrome, I can go to `chrome://extensions/` and click "permissions" to view the permissions that an installed extension has been granted.  I cannot find an equivalent in Firefox. Is there such a resource? In Firefox, `about:permissions` has per-site permissions, which is a great resource but I need per-extension permissions. (`Firefox version = 23.0.1`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [this document](http://www.intelligentexploit.com/articles/Abusing,-Exploiting-and-Pwning-with-Firefox-Add-ons.pdf). Relevant excerpt (page 3):

> The Firefox platform has no mechanisms to restrict the privileges of add-ons. The add-on code is
>   fully trusted by Firefox. The installation of malicious add-ons can result in full system
>   compromise. There is no security measure to restrict the intercommunication between add-ons.
>   As a result an add-on can alter or modify another add-on in the background. There is no security
>   policy or sandboxing ability of XPConnect and XPCOM components which is a serious flaw in the
>   security
>   model. Firefox does not have any type of restrictions on malformed Cross Origin
>   Resource Sharing and socket creation. Some exploitable vulnerabilities are platform
>   independent.

So there is no way to show per add-on permissions because there are *no permissions to show*. In the Firefox security model, each add-on is roughly equivalent to a piece of native code, which can, by definition, do whatever it wants. This is similar to the situation with signed Java applets.

Comment: This Q&A [**needs updating**](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2018/02/01/understanding-extension-permission-requests/) to 2018 (five years on, Firefox 60+; addons >> webextensions).

Answer (score 4):

As of Firefox Quantum (v. 57+), there is an add-on, [Project Insight](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/project-insight/?src=search), to show the permissions of other add-ons (and itself).

[image: Project Insight display]

Note that it only displays *active* add-ons, so at least temporarily, enable all.

Comment: Of two suggested FF extensions only the second one - Permission Inspector - seems to be working correctly. Project Insight doesn't report permissions correctly. To see that it's enough to compare what is stated on Ghostery – Privacy Ad Blocker extension page and what Project Insight reports: missing is information about rather important permission "Access your data for all websites".

Answer (score 3):

[Permission Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/permission-inspector/) add-on displays the permissions granted, including those for disabled add-ons. It also displays all extensions having a particlular permission.

[image: By extension]

[image: By permission]